# Submit a form with a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a simple thing, but I don't know how:

I have a table with some records... I would like to put in a select field that shows a records view from the table. My select field is

```
<select>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

When the user clicks one of the four options (for example, 10), I need to reload the page and get the value 10... So I can change the query in the database. I could do this with a submit button, but is horrible to see. Because you have to choose and afterwards click the submit button every time.

I prefer just to choose the value from the select field and after the page reload... Is it possible?

Comment: man...why reload the page.dint you hear anything about AJAX

Comment: Have you considered using [datatables](http://datatables.net/)?

Comment: use anchor tags in each option, href would be the php file and get the value from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code

```
<select name="select" id="select" onchange="reload_page_for_DB(this.value);">
  <option value="">Please choose an option</option>
  <option value="?db_value=5">5</option>
  <option value="?db_value=10">10</option>
  <option value="?db_value=15">15</option>
  <option value="?db_value=20">20</option>
</select>
```

Javascript functions

```
<script>

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function reload_page_for_DB(value){
   if(value != ''){
    var dbIndexValue = document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex;
    createCookie('dbIndexValue',dbIndexValue,0);
    parent.location = value;
   }
}

function selected_index(){
   var dbIndexValue = readCookie('dbIndexValue');
   if(dbIndexValue != null){
    document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = dbIndexValue;
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = 0;
   }
}
selected_index();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### There are two methods for this

The first method is using simple form submission.

The second way is the usage of [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). This way you won't have to save the select value and you will get the result on the page without even having to reload the page.

The easy way of doing this is using Ajax! But if you do not prefer Ajax and want to reload the page then you can do this!

#### Form submission

```
$('select').change(function () { // Change in the select element
    $(this.form).submit(); // Submit its form!
}
```

Now on the server-side get the results from the database. But note that you will be using the same number to reselect the select statement!

Let me give you an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) example; since I am aware of that, but this will give you the idea!

```
<select>
  <option @if(selected_value == '5') {selected} value="5">5</option>
  <option @if(selected_value == '10') {selected} value="10">10</option>
  <option @if(selected_value == '15') {selected} value="15">15</option>
  <option @if(selected_value == '20') {selected} value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

I am using a variable for the `selected_value` and then using an `if else` block to test its validity for the condition. If true then selecting the value using `selected` attribute. If not true then moving on to the next one!

`selected` attribute is a boolean value, so you can use any of these!

1. `selected`
2. `selected=""`
3. `selected="selected"`.

They would all work perfectly.

#### Using Ajax

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url_from_where/page_would_be_loaded.html',
        data: $(this.form).serialize(); // Serialize current form or use only
        data: 'selected_value=' + $(this).val();
        success: function (data) {
          // Show the results on the page!
        }
    })
}
```

#### For more information, see:

- *[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)* (jQuery change method)
- *[Category: Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)* (jQuery Ajax)
- *[<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)*  (select HTML)

Comment: @GiovanniFar, I am really very sorry brother I am not good in PHP, so I won't share a vague and useless code to waste your time. You can search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.your-form').submit();
});
```

You need to assign a class or id to your form to select it (in my case I have used class `your-form`).

Or try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Obviously, you need to include this code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: This will submit the page and get the results, but it will also deselect the value in the select after the page reloads.

Comment: he has to make a control in php or other language to check the get value isn't specified @RutwickGangurde

Comment: i insert this code and also give a class to my form... but it doesnt works... can u show to me an example please?

Comment: something like this but is more little you need to check the value after submit  (I don't know if you use php or not) http://jsfiddle.net/9gGG5/ @GiovanniFar

Comment: i checked ur example but i receive this when i click something Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted....this code have to be inside in the head ?? with the tag:<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Okay... But he'll need the entire example!